When starting a new job, is it OK to point out someone else (on the team) taught me a different way?
I recently started a new job. It's going fairly well. I've been told we don't have documentation (or at least the existing one is out of date / corrupt). As such, I've been asking a lot of questions. In past jobs I have occasionally gotten the feedback that I ask too many questions. But without documentation, I don't see an alternative, except for guessing and waiting for someone to point out a mistake. I've noticed different people do things differently and the process isn't streamlined. For example some people say to include certain information in certain emails, but others don't. When inconsistencies like this happen should I bring it up or ask clarifying questions? Being new I don't want to rock the boat.
Also, I had been trying to ask questions in the group chat. But I found it confusing when several people chime in and give different (sometimes partial) answers. As one example, I asked what I thought was a yes/no question (should I include x when I'm setting up account y). After 20 minutes of discussion, I still was unclear of the answer. So I've been messaging one I find explains things clearly. But I don't want to irritate him with too many questions. Should I point out any of this to anyone, for example if my manager asks me if I'm experiencing any roadblocks?

I am going to answer this question tangentially:
You should ask the question, document the answer, then send the link to your team to review
Consider a process, it is undocumented, you ask 10 people how to do it and you get 10 different answers.
Which way is the right way - Who knows!
Now, consider a process, it now has documentation, it has a right way of doing it - perhaps one of the different ways has an advantage or something that is important The person who does it differently now either updates the documentation or the team agrees this is a better way to do it and then the documentation gets updated
Although this doesnt address your immediate question - In the long run, it does address it, because there will be a written way of doing things, which will become the de-facto correct way of doing things

Shades of Cunningham's Law

I have done this. I think part of the problem is there's "partial documentation" scattered in various places (e.g. one training video here, one cheat sheet there etc.). Should I suggest to the team to use the copy I created to add everything and make it the defacto?

In a previous meeting when I brought up the lack of documentation, multiple people said they "can't make documentation". Should I ask what is meant by this? In a sense, what I mean by making documentation is that instead of having various steps scattered through out group chats, put them all in one place. I think what happened was the original document got lost and they have only had PDF versions which are not editable.

@ClanLatin - I will answer with two maxims: Build it and they will come and easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. I would create your documents from whatever info you have, put it all in a single publicly accessible location (Sharepoint, Confluence, File server etc.) - then let the team know and raise it in a meeting.


Should I point out any of this to anyone, for example if my manager asks me if I'm experiencing any roadblocks?

Yes. That's what your manager is for. Ask them about the best/preferred of getting information especially in the absence of decent documentation. Describe what you are currently doing, what you think works, what doesn't, what other options you have considered and ask for guidance.
You can also actively seek out other people that have started recently and probably tackling the same problem. You can share experience and tips and tricks so you can benefit what from other people's learnings (and the other way around). If you are working in office, you can host a once a week or once every two weeks "newbie coffee". Bringing some donuts will help with attendance.

I only ever talk to my manager in daily meetings where 10 other people present. I'm concerned if I bring this up in one it might upset the other people. Would you advise to discuss this with the manager over messenger, over a call, or just say it in the meeting?

I'd advise you to walk into your manager's office, and say, "Hey, got a minute to advise me on something, or should we schedule a one-on-one?"

@keshlam good idea but the work is remote.

@ClanLatin: schedule a 1:1 meeting. 30 minutes. remote is fine.

I don't want to embarrass anyone but would it be helpful if I have specific examples to show to the manager. For example "when I asked what I thought was a yes or no question, Joe replied and after 20 minutes of discussion I was still unclear on the answer" and show him the thread?

@ClanLatin: Yes. Just make sure that the examples are clear and really make your point. The example you picked feels a bit fuzzy to me.

@Hilmar I would like to run another example by you: "I was trained to check if a user account with the same name exists before creating a new account. I wasn't told what to do in the case that one already existed. I recently encountered this scenario and asked someone what to do. She said the account was expired so make a new one. I asked how she knew that the account was expired. She said because the password was. I pointed out I found it confusing because in another field it said the account was enabled. She didn't reply". Is this a good example or is it fuzzy?

@ClanLatin: that sounds very fuzzy to me. Why didn't you ask when you were trained to check for duplicates? The person who "trained" you to check for duplicates should have specified what to do with the duplicates once you found them.


I've been told we don't have documentation (or at least the existing one is out of date / corrupt).

I've got to the cynical stage of thinking that, for most companies, it is absurd to think there even would be documentation.
I've worked in some big companies where the majority of staff struggle to even correspond in writing about narrow issues, and some struggle to even talk straight, let alone write a textbook of all the knowledge a new trainee would require to execute an entire job without asking questions of anybody. It's just not how the world works.
The jobs that are relatively procedural and repetitive and involve a large enough workforce to justify competent auxiliary staff being employed to author documentation about those jobs, are a shrinking number of the jobs that exist in the economy, taken over instead by machinery and computerisation.
It's never been normal for the content of most jobs to exist as documentation and manuals that new staff simply study and follow without input from experienced staff.

I've noticed different people do things differently and the process isn't streamlined. For example some people say to include certain information in certain emails, but others don't. When inconsistencies like this happen should I bring it up or ask clarifying questions? Being new I don't want to rock the boat.

If you're being told to do things two different ways, then you can certainly ask. Sometimes, one person is simply more careful and fastidious than another.
It might ultimately be up to you to decide what standard you want to set. You might not specifically want to draw the attention of either of your teachers to the variation, because either might then be insulted if you don't adopt their standard, and by trying to purge the variation you might also be trying to iron out inconsistencies in the competence or underlying personality of your different teachers (an act that would be prescribed to fail, and cause bad will towards you).

So I've been messaging one I find explains things clearly. But I don't want to irritate him with too many questions.

Only you can judge. People who are visibly skilled at explaining typically acquire such skill because they enjoy training and exercising those skills and being recognised for them, provided you aren't putting so much demand on them at once that they become tired mentally from it or unable to progress with their ordinary duties.
Unless your questions are repetitive or lacking common sense, or too subtle for the person being asked, then most people are indulgent towards new colleagues, and if they were becoming over-tired would simply act to limit you without there being any bad feeling, as with adults and inquisitive children sometimes.

Should I point out any of this to anyone, for example if my manager asks me if I'm experiencing any roadblocks?

It doesn't sound like there's any cause for complaint at this stage, and if there was, you'd often find even greater incompetence at the higher levels. I struggle to think of a workplace where a team which comes across as chaotic to a new trainee, and where the issue is genuinely the team and not the trainee, could coexist with a competent manager - so the problem is either with you, or it is with the manager to whom you are considering complaining.

"I've worked in some big companies where the majority of staff struggle to even correspond in writing about narrow issues, and some struggle to even talk straight," I sometimes wonder how this happens? Presumably they were able to figure out how to apply for the job and pass the interview.

@ClanLatin, I think sometimes it's because the company has grown, or it's a smaller division that was merged into the bigger company, and the tide has therefore lifted certain staff who are then ill-equipped for the complexity. But as I say, even in companies with stronger capabilities, it's not my experience to find everything about a job written down as a training curriculum. Even companies that actually have training curriculums, have trainers to deliver and demonstrate it, and workshops for the delivery - the trainees don't just read it all themselves. (1/2)

The point of my remark about people not even talking straight, is to emphasise just how far the average staff member is from the capability of writing a hypothetical manual for their job. Almost anything that is easy to proceduralise, is nowadays easy to computerise or automate, so the jobs that remain to be described and filled by trainees, are always a residue of complicated tasks requiring intelligent management, ongoing monitoring and coordination, or (even if routine in theory...) frequent fast adaptation in a way that does not reconcile with writing static documentation. (2/2)

Most people on my team have terrible spelling and grammar. This makes me take longer to read and understand what they have wrote, and they've been wondering why I've been going slow. Honestly it's not the biggest barrier, but it certainly is one of them. Should I point this out? For example normally one sentence isn't 5 lines long.

@ClanLatin, no, spelling and grammar is not something I'd usually raise with the person themselves as a free-standing point. I once worked for a firm where we'd all laugh at how garbled email comms were from a particular pair of manager and deputy - we'd all gather round deciphering, before deciding whether to ask a clarifying question. They'd both been grandfathered-in due to company growth over several preceding years. Neither had capability to improve. (1/2)

Sometimes it's best to just move onto a new firm where your skills are more suited and procedures are more coherent. Fools with no conscientiousness can sometimes thrive under conditions where intelligent people get bogged down trying to clarify subtleties and contradictions. (2/2)

Re: "The jobs that are relatively procedural and repetitive...are a shrinking number " I think my job does fall into this unlikely category. I've been working on automating it (which I think is the right approach because manually repeating the same task 100s of times is very error prone) but I haven't told anyone.

@ClanLatin, but does it "involve a large enough workforce to justify competent auxiliary staff being employed to author documentation"? My argument is not that work no longer has any routine element for anyone, it is that the scale of workforce employed on any one routine, and the stability of any one routine over time, is quite small, meaning it isn't economical to employ someone else to write a book on a job that only one person is doing for a short while before it has to change again. (1/2)

You are saving yourself perceived drudgery by devising a mechanisation, but your job is then machine-minding, maintaining an understanding of what it does and how it works to serve its purpose, and re-adapting the bespoke workings quickly when necessary. Actually writing up how to do that residual supervisory part of your job (rather than writing up the machine's job) was not only difficult when you were doing the drudgery manually, but even moreso now that your job involves an element of machine design (software development). (2/2)
